# Find two lines around which points were randomly generated

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

Given a list of points that were randomly generated around two lines, find two new lines that match the original lines as closely as possible. Here's the function definition:

```
getLinesOfBestFit(x: numpy.array, y: numpy.array) -> Tuple[Line, Line]

Line = namedtuple('Line', [('m', float), ('b', float)])
```

I saw that there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349148/fitting-two-lines-to-a-set-of-2d-points) about this problem already on StackOverflow, however, I found it difficult to understand. Please help me with understanding. I would like a solution that doesn't rely too heavily on libraries other than `numpy` so that I can understand the principles being applied.

I can use `polyfit` to find the line of best fit for a set of points as follows:

```
m, b = numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)
```

However, before I can do this approach I need to split the set of input points into two sets of points, one set for each line. Naively, I can achieve that by considering all possible lines, then finding the two lines that minimise the distance of all points from any line. This approach is very inefficient though.

Comment: This falls into the general class of [clustering problems](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html), but given you have prior knowledge about the points it's unlikely you'll find something more efficient and robust than a minimization approach like that you have suggested. It doesn't seem like it should be that expensive though. How are you solving the minimization problem?

Comment: Ad-hoc method, probably more efficient ones exist: Construct a "medium dense" covering of the upper half of the 2-sphere with points $(a_m,b_m,c_m)$ (more than cube, dodecahedron density should be enough). Assign points $(x_k,y_k)$ of the input sequence to the sphere points per the minimum of the distance to the represented line $|amx_k+b_my_k+c_m|$. Select the sphere points with the longest list of assigned points, do linear regression on these points, clean up the remaining points, repeat regression.

Comment: Is anything known about the two lines, e.g. are they parallel?  Is anything known about the two sets of points, e.g. that the number of points scattered about each of the two lines is the same?  I get the impression that these are "lines" in 2 dimensions, but a similar problem could be posed in higher dimensions.  Information about how the "random generation" of points is done should prove valuable.

Comment: @hardmath there are no constraints on the original lines. They are completely random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This falls into the general class of [clustering problems](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html). After the points are clustered it is straight forward to fit the two lines; however, it is possible to directly formulate it as an unconstrained least squares problem in terms of the distance of each point to the closest of the two candidate lines.

Given data $(x_i, y_i)$ formulate formulate a residual sum of squares as
$$
J(b_1, m_1, b_2, m_2) = \sum_i \operatorname{min}( |y_i - (m_1 x_i - b_1)|^2, |y_i - (m_2 x_i - b_2)|^2)
$$
then solve for the estimates $\hat b_1, \hat m_1, \hat b_2, \hat m_2 = \arg \min J(b_1, m_1, b_2, m_2)$

A potential issue with this approach is  that the residual function is non-differentiable for certain values of the parameters. (If this will be a practical issue is probably data specific). One way around this would be to use a smooth-min function, but in practice using a conditional may work.

The following code implements the naive (non smooth minimum) approach.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

# Generate example data for two lines
b1,m1 = 2, 4
b2,m2 = 3,-3
n_samples = 1000
x1 = np.random.rand(n_samples)
y1 = b1 + m1*x1
x2 = np.random.rand(n_samples)
y2 = b2 + m2*x2
data =  np.hstack([[x1,y1], [x2,y2]])

# Define a residual function to minimize
def residual(x, data):
""" 
Input
    x (array): m1, b1, m2, b2
    data (array 2 x N): first row x-values and second row y-values of   data
Returns: 
    min_err (array N): min_err[k] is the y-distance of each point in data[:, k] to
                       either b=x[0] m=x[1]  or b=x[2] m=x[3], whichever is smaller
"""
    l1_err = data[0] * x[1] + x[0] - data[1]
    l2_err = data[0] * x[3] + x[2] - data[1]
    min_err = np.where(np.abs(l1_err) < np.abs(l2_err), l1_err, l2_err)
    return min_err

# Set initial guess of intercepts and slopes for two lines
x0 = 0, 0, 1, 1 # m1, b1, m2, b2
result = least_squares(residual, x0, args=(data,)) #Finds the correct 
print(result.x)
# >>> 3, -3, 2, 4
```

You could likely use some heuristic to get good initial estimates for `x0`, e.g. find the approximate "corners" of the points and find the lines going through those points at a cross.

This approach could be generalized to higher dimensions, but the parameterization of the lines would be a bit different (each line would require a point and a direction vector), and one would likely want to compute the orthogonal distance to the each line unless there is some reason to prefer one coordinate to another.

As a final note, given the specific form of the problem, the non-convex optimization procedures noted in the answers to [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349148/fitting-two-lines-to-a-set-of-2d-points), may be more robust than this approach.

Comment: Thank you @user9794, however, this solution does not answer the question. This solution assumes that we already know which points belong to which line. However, the original question states that we get a list of coordinates as input and we do not know which coordinate belongs to which line.

Comment: How so? The first part of the code is just to generate some example data. The function `residual` does not know anything about which line a given point `data[:,k]` belongs to. For all points it computes the y-distance between each line and returns distance to the closest line for each point. Then the input parameters, `x`, are adjusted until each point has a minimum distance to one of the two lines.

Comment: Thank you @user9794, this makes sense! Thank you for clarifying return types. I find Python rather difficult to read given the lack of types. Thank you for making the types more explicit.